Calculating Wet Season Average Precipitation Data in Google Earth Engine
I want to extract and create a map visualizing the average precipitation data between the years 2000-2023 during the wet seasons only, i.e.(Nov-Mar). However each time I run the code I get this error:

Wet Season Precipitation (2000-2023): Layer error: reduce.mean: Error
in map(ID=0): Image.date: Image '0' does not have a
'system:time_start' property.

Here's the code:
// Define wet season months (replace with your region's wet months)
var wetSeasonMonths = [11, 12, 0, 1, 2, 3];  // Adjust as needed (e.g., November to April)

// Load precipitation data (replace 'your_precipitation_data' with your actual data)
var precipitation = ee.ImageCollection('UCSB-CHG/CHIRPS/PENTAD').filterDate('2000-01-01', '2023-12-31');

// Calculate monthly precipitation by averaging daily values
var monthlyPrecipitation = precipitation.mean().select('precipitation');

// Function to filter data for wet season months
function filterWetSeason(image) {
  var month = image.date().get('month');
return image.set('season', ee.Algorithms.If(ee.List(wetSeasonMonths).contains(month), 1, 0));
}

// Convert monthlyPrecipitation to an ImageCollection (if needed)
var monthlyPrecipCollection = ee.ImageCollection([monthlyPrecipitation]);

// Apply filterWetSeason function with map
var wetSeasonPrecipitation = monthlyPrecipCollection.map(filterWetSeason)
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('season', 1))
  .mean(); 
  
// Define visualization parameters (adjust as needed)
var visParams = {
  min: 0,
  max: 500,  // Adjust for your precipitation data range
  palette: ['blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange', 'red']
};

// Visualization (optional)
Map.centerObject(roi, 10); // Replace 'geometry' with your area of interest
Map.addLayer(wetSeasonPrecipitation.clip(roi), visParams, 'Wet Season Precipitation (2000-2023)');

// Export the wet season precipitation image (modify for your desired output)
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: wetSeasonPrecipitation,
  description: 'WetSeasonPrecipitation_2000_2023',
  scale: 30, // Adjust scale if needed
  fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF' // Choose your preferred format
});


Here are some notes:

I've changed the date range to include images from November 1999 until April 2024. In GEE, the end date is not included in the range, hence the date 2024-05-01.
I used toBands() to make it easier to export the result.

var years = ee.List.sequence(2020, 2024);
var wetSeasonMonths = [11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4];

// Load the CHIRPS precipitation dataset and filter for the wet season months
var precipitation = ee.ImageCollection('UCSB-CHG/CHIRPS/PENTAD')
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('1999-11-01', '2024-05-01')) // Date range for filtering
  .filter(ee.Filter.inList('month', wetSeasonMonths));
  
var images = years.map(function(currentYear) {
  currentYear = ee.Number(currentYear);
  
  // Get the previous year.
  var previousYear = currentYear.subtract(1);
  
  // Define the wet season months for the previous year.
  var previousYearMonths = [11, 12];
  
  // Filter precipitation images for the previous year's wet season months.
  var previousYearImages = precipitation
    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(previousYear, previousYear, 'year'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.inList('month', previousYearMonths));
  
  // Define the wet season months for the current year.
  var currentYearMonths = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  
  // Filter precipitation images for the current year's wet season months.
  var currentYearImages = precipitation
    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(currentYear, currentYear, 'year'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.inList('month', currentYearMonths));
  
  // Merge the previous and current year's images into a single collection.
  var images = previousYearImages.merge(currentYearImages);
  
  // Create a band name in the format "YYYY_YYYY" (e.g., "2020_2021").
  var bandName = previousYear.format('%d').cat('_').cat(currentYear.format('%d'));
  
  // Calculate the mean precipitation for the merged images and rename the band.
  var mean = images.mean().rename(bandName);
  
  return mean;
});

// Convert the list of images into an ImageCollection - this is the result.
images = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(images);
print('Result', images);

// Visualize the first image (2019-2020 mean).
var first = ee.Image(images.first());
Map.addLayer(first.clip(roi), {
  min: 0,
  max: 12,
  palette: ['white', 'blue']
}, '2019-2020');

// Export
var exportImage = images.toBands();
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: exportImage, 
  description: '2020_2024_Wet_Season_Precipitation', 
  folder: 'folder_name', 
  fileNamePrefix: 'file_name', 
  region: roi, 
  scale: 5566,
  // crs: '', // Set if needed.
  maxPixels: 1e10 // Adjust if needed.
});

Script
